# Exchange limit on bounds of Lebesgue integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(E_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of measurable sets such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} E_n =E$ for some measurable set $E$. When does it hold that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{E_n}f d \mu = \int_{E}f d\mu$$
What if we replace $\lim$ with $\lim \sup$ or $\lim \inf$?

Comment: Does it help if you write $\displaystyle\int_{E_n} f\,d\mu = \displaystyle\int_E f\chi_{E_n}\,d\mu$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes I tried that. At least for positive $f$ wouldn't that imply that this is always true? The limit and the integral can be exchanged because $f\chi_{E_n}$ is non-decreasing.

Comment: What kind of function is $f$? What do you mean by $\lim_{n \to \infty} E_n =E$?

Comment: @BigbearZzz See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit

Comment: @JannikPitt Is $f$ integrable? Locally integrable?

Comment: @BigbearZzz I wonder when this identity holds, so it can be either.

Comment: @JannikPitt I added some other interpretations of your statement in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be an integrable function. i.e. $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$. Then we have $|f\chi_{E_n}|\le |f|$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, hence by Dominated Convergence Theorem we have
$$\begin{align}
\int_Ef\,d\mu &= \int f\chi_E\,d\mu \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int f\chi_{E_n} \,d\mu \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{E_n} f\,d\mu
\end{align}$$
provided that $\chi_{E_n}\to\chi_E$ almost everywhere.

> The pointwise convergence a.e. of $\chi_{E_n}$ can be a result of letting $$E=\bigcup_n E_n, $$
>   for example, or even a weaker hypothesis like $E=\liminf_{n\to\infty} E_n$, i.e.
>   $$
> E = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k\ge n} E_k.
> $$

If we only assume that $f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Bbb R)$ then the previous convergent result still holds, provided that we assume further that $E,E_n$ are contained in some bounded set $B\subset \Bbb R$ (because we can apply the above argument by viewing $f\in L^1(B)$).

If $f$ is not even locally integrable, then we can find counterexamples so that $\int_Ef\,d\mu \ne \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{E_n} f\,d\mu$.

---

> Alternatively, we can consider the pseudo-distance function 
>   $$
> d(A,B) := \mu(A\Delta B)
> $$
>   defined on $\mathcal A$, the family of Lebesgue measurable sets of $\Bbb R$. Define the equivalent relation $A\sim B$ iff $d(A,B)=0$, then the set of equivalent classes $\mathcal A/\sim$ forms a (complete) metric space. We can now interpret $E = \lim_{n\to\infty} E_n$ as 
>   $$
> d(E,E_n) \to 0
> $$
>   in $\mathcal A/\sim$.

Now, any $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$ induces an absolutely continuous signed measure on $\Bbb R$. Hence for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can find a number $\delta>0$ such that $\mu(A)<\delta$ implies
$$
\int_A |f|\,d\mu < \varepsilon.
$$
Thus for sufficiently large $n$, we have
$$
\left| \int_E f\,d\mu - \int_{E_n} f\,d\mu \right|\le \int_{E\Delta E_n} |f|\,d\mu < \varepsilon
$$
since $\mu(E\Delta E_n)\to 0$. This shows that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{E_n}f d \mu = \int_{E}f d\mu$.

---

Similarly, if we instead assume $f\in L^\infty (\Bbb R)$ then for sufficiently large $n$ we have
$$
\left| \int_E f\,d\mu - \int_{E_n} f\,d\mu \right|\le \int_{E\Delta E_n} |f|\,d\mu \le \mu(E\Delta E_n) ||f||_\infty \to 0
$$
as $d(E,E_n)\to 0$, which implies $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{E_n}f d \mu = \int_{E}f d\mu$ also.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

Take the Lebesgue measured space $(\mathbb R, \mu)$, $E_n= (-\infty, 1/n)$ and

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x \le 0\\
1/x & x>0
\end{cases}$$

Then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}E_n =(-\infty , 0]$. And

$$\infty = \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{E_n}f d \mu \neq \int_{E}f d\mu =0$$